# How to call Wordpress post featured image instead of static url

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Trying to add this image hover effect to the featured image in a blog post template in Wordpress. Currently the JS is calling an image URL, but I want the effect to target the featured image of the post template. I think it may be possible using PHP in the JS file but im not sure how to do it, can anyone help me out please?

```js
// options
var options = {
  imgSrc : "https://unsplash.it/g/1024/768?image=887",
  containerName : "tileContainer",
  grid : false,
  tileWidth : 80,
  tileHeight : 80,
  mouseTrail:true
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
var tileWidth, tileHeight, numTiles, tileHolder, tileContainer;
var directionX, directionY;
var imgOriginalWidth, imgOriginalHeight;
var imgCoverWidth, imgCoverHeight;
var imageLoaded = false;

numTiles=0;
tileWidth = options.tileWidth;
tileHeight = options.tileHeight;

tileContainer = document.getElementsByClassName(options.containerName)[0];

function init(){
  if(options.grid == false)tileContainer.className += " noGrid";
  
  //preload image and get original image size, then create tiles
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = options.imgSrc;
  image.onload = function(e){
    imageLoaded = true;
    imgOriginalWidth = e.currentTarget.width;
    imgOriginalHeight = e.currentTarget.height;
    
    createTileHolder();
    checkTileNumber();
    positionImage();
    addListeners();
  };  
}

function resizeHandler()
{
  if(imageLoaded == false)return;
  
  //not working yet
  
  checkTileNumber();
  positionImage();
}

function createTileHolder(){
  tileHolder = document.createElement('div');
  tileHolder.className = "tileHolder";
  tileHolder.style.position = "absolute";
  tileHolder.style.top = "50%";
  tileHolder.style.left = "50%";
  tileHolder.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
  tileContainer.appendChild(tileHolder);
}

function checkTileNumber()
{
  tileHolder.style.width = Math.ceil(tileContainer.offsetWidth / tileWidth) * tileWidth + "px";
  tileHolder.style.height = Math.ceil(tileContainer.offsetHeight / tileHeight) * tileHeight + "px";
  
  var tilesFitInWindow = Math.ceil(tileContainer.offsetWidth / tileWidth) * Math.ceil(tileContainer.offsetHeight / tileHeight);
  if(numTiles < tilesFitInWindow){
    for (var i=0, l=tilesFitInWindow-numTiles; i < l; i++){
      addTiles();
    }
  }else if(numTiles > tilesFitInWindow){
      for (var i=0, l=numTiles-tilesFitInWindow; i < l; i++){
        removeTiles();
      }
  }  
}


function addTiles()
{
  var tile = document.createElement('div');
  tile.className = "tile";  
  
  //maintain aspect ratio
  imgCoverWidth = tileContainer.offsetWidth;
  imgCoverHeight = tileContainer.offsetHeight;

  if(imgOriginalWidth > imgOriginalHeight){
        imgCoverHeight = imgOriginalHeight / imgOriginalWidth * imgCoverWidth;
    }else{
        imgCoverWidth = imgOriginalWidth / imgOriginalHeight * imgCoverHeight;     
    } 
  
  
  tile.style.background = 'url("'+options.imgSrc+'") no-repeat';
  tile.style.backgroundSize  = imgCoverWidth + "px " +  imgCoverHeight + "px";
  tile.style.width = tileWidth + "px";
  tile.style.height = tileHeight + "px";
  document.querySelectorAll(".tileHolder")[0].appendChild(tile);
  
  tile.addEventListener("mouseover", moveImage);  
  
  numTiles++;
}

function removeTiles()
{
  var tileToRemove = document.querySelectorAll(".tile")[0];
  tileToRemove.removeEventListener("mouseover", moveImage); 
  
  TweenMax.killTweensOf(tileToRemove);
  tileToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(tileToRemove);
  
  numTiles--;
}

function addListeners(){
 if(options.mouseTrail){
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
      directionX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
      directionY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;
    });
  }
}

function positionImage(){
  for(var t=0, l=numTiles; t < l; t++)
  {
    var nowTile = document.querySelectorAll(".tile")[t];
   
    var left = (-nowTile.offsetLeft - (tileHolder.offsetLeft - (tileHolder.offsetWidth/2)));
    var top = (-nowTile.offsetTop - (tileHolder.offsetTop - (tileHolder.offsetHeight/2)));
    
    nowTile.style.backgroundPosition = left + "px " + top + "px";
  }
}

function resetImage(nowTile){    
  var left = (-nowTile.offsetLeft - (tileHolder.offsetLeft - (tileHolder.offsetWidth/2)));
  var top = (-nowTile.offsetTop - (tileHolder.offsetTop - (tileHolder.offsetHeight/2)));
  
  
  TweenMax.to(nowTile, 1, {backgroundPosition:left + "px " + top + "px", ease:Power1.easeInOut});
}


function moveImage(e){
  var nowTile = e.currentTarget
  var minWidth = -tileContainer.offsetWidth+nowTile.offsetWidth;
  var minHeight = -tileContainer.offsetHeight+nowTile.offsetHeight;
  var nowLeftPos = (-nowTile.offsetLeft - (tileHolder.offsetLeft - (tileHolder.offsetWidth/2)));
  var nowTopPos = (-nowTile.offsetTop - (tileHolder.offsetTop - (tileHolder.offsetHeight/2)))
  var offset = 60;
  var left = nowLeftPos;
  var top = nowTopPos;
    
  if(options.mouseTrail){
    //direction-aware movement
    if(directionX > 0){
      left = nowLeftPos + offset;
    }else if(directionX < 0){
      left = nowLeftPos - offset;
    }
    
    if(directionY > 0){
      top = nowTopPos + offset;
    }else if(directionY < 0){
      top = nowTopPos - offset;
    }
  }else{
    //random movement
    left = getRandomInt(nowLeftPos - offset , nowLeftPos + offset);
    top = getRandomInt(nowTopPos - offset, nowTopPos + offset);
  }
    
  // bounds
  if(left < minWidth)left=minWidth;
  if(left > 0)left=0;
  if(top < minHeight)top=minHeight;
  if(top > 0)top=0;
  
  //tween
  TweenMax.to(nowTile, 1.5, {backgroundPosition:left + "px " + top + "px", ease:Power1.easeOut, onComplete:resetImage, onCompleteParams:[nowTile]});
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

init();
// handle event
//window.addEventListener("optimizedResize", resizeHandler);

////////////////////////UTILS//////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

(function() {
    var throttle = function(type, name, obj) {
        obj = obj || window;
        var running = false;
        var func = function() {
            if (running) { return; }
            running = true;
             requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
                running = false;
            });
        };
        obj.addEventListener(type, func);
    };

    /* init - you can init any event */
    throttle("resize", "optimizedResize");
})();
```

```css
body{background-color:#1A1919;text-align:center;}

.tileContainer{
  border:10px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:1024px;
  height:768px;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


.tile{
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
  border-right:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.tile:after{
  content:"";
  background-color:#cc1c32;
  width:6px;
  height:6px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  right:0px;
  transform:translate(50%, -50%);
  z-index:2;
  line-height:1;
}

/*-- no grid --*/

.noGrid .tile{
  border-right:0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom:0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.noGrid .tile:after{
  content:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tileContainer">

</div>
```

Comment: I hope this will solve your query. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215181/retrieving-featured-image-on-static-blog-posts-page

Comment: thanks Adnan, Im not entirely sure how to implement this code into the existing code though. Are you able to edit my code above to show me please?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158491/is-it-possible-set-a-featured-image-with-external-image-url

Hey just make a try from this link so that you can have better understanding with your code what you are doing and what exactly need to do.

Comment: Are you saying you want the featured image to be fetched from the backend during runtime by the browser? The more normal thing would be to get the backend/server PHP to send it as part of writing the page. (probably from code in something like a single-...php file) in the theme.